# Nativescript API call return with HttpErrorResponse

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Trying to access the following API but keep getting an error when access it.  The url is correct and works perfectly when run through postman.

```
let data = this.http.get<any>('http://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/retrieve/registry/lat/53.790224/long/-1.563929/dist/3/format/json');
```

Just this call alone returns this error

```
CONSOLE ERROR
file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:15769:28: 
ERROR {
    "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null,
    "headers": {}
},
"status": 0,
"statusText": "Unknown Error",
"url":"http://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/retrieve/registry/lat/53.790224/long/-1.563929/dist/3",
"ok": false,
"name": "HttpErrorResponse",
"message": "Http failure response for http://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/retrieve/registry/lat/53.790224/long/-1.563929/dist/3: 0 Unknown Error",
"error": {
"line": 1298,
"column": 38,
"sourceURL": "file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js",
"originalStack": "ZoneAwareError@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:1298:38\nfile:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/http/http-request/http-request.js:97:37\nUIApplicationMain@[native code]\n_start@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:275:26\nrun@file:///app/tns_mo<…>
```

If I simply change the path to a different api it works absolutely fine.
Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what i'm missing.

So i've updated the AndroidManifest and that works fine now, however via iOs I still get the same problem.

Comment: CORS issue probably

Comment: what is this `this.http.get[any]` about? does that even work?

Comment: @Reactgular There's a `nb` about the return type... don't know why, but seems OP cannot write `<any>` ??

Comment: @AJT_82 thank you. The OP was using `<pre>` tags in the markdown editor.

Comment: @Reactgular Yeah, I saw. Was just editing the post when you edited it :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nativescript: HTTP failure response for unknown URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018049/nativescript-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url) / [Http request fail on NativeScript Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012342/http-request-fail-on-nativescript-angular)

Comment: I am using <any> just for some reason couldn't get it in the editor - kept stripping it out

Comment: Thank's Manoj.  Working in both iOs and android from both of those articles.

Answer (score 0):

you need pass content type in your HTTP call

```
let httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders(
                    {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    })}

 this.http.get<any>(url, httpOptions).subscribe(payloadResponse => {
                        console.log('response received', payloadResponse);                            
                    }, error => {
                      // failed 
                    });
```